# Diff Docker containers for wso2-am product profiles

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Im trying to deploy wso2-am 1.10.0 in a docker container. 
To have clear separation between components we would like to spin up separate clusters (docker containers) for gateway workers, store/publisher, gateway managers and key managers. Could you please point me an example of how to achieve this? I was able to follow instructions in https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles 
and build a docker image of the product. But i would like to have different containers for diff wso2-am product profiles. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to spawn different cluster patterns with WSO2 APIM, you can look at the docker-compose aproach used [here](https://github.com/gayangunarathne/Docker-compose/tree/master/wso2-products/WSO2APIM/1.10).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that in the docker compose file, I see the referenence to svnrepo and mgt.gw.apim.wso2.org service. Also it looks like the dockerhub.private.wso2.com is not accessible. Could you please help?

Comment: Above is a WSO2 internal Docker registry. We are now working on hosting a public registry. For the time being please get those Docker images built using https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles. Once the images are built change the image ids in the compose file accordingly.

Comment: Could you please share the timeline on when that will be released?